# $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+a}} > \sqrt{a+b+c}$ is true for positive a,b,c

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do you prove that for all positive $a,b,c$ this formula holds true:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+a}} > \sqrt{a+b+c}?
\end{equation*}

Any help will be invaluable.

Answer (score 6):

Since

$$a+b+c=\sqrt{(a+b+c)^2}=\sqrt{a+b+c}\ \sqrt{a+b+c}\iff \dfrac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}=\sqrt{a+b+c}$$

and

$$\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}>\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}$$

$$\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b+c}}>\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}$$

$$\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{c+a}}>\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}$$

we have

$$\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b+c}}+\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{c+a}}>\dfrac{a+b+c}{%
\sqrt{a+b+c}}=\sqrt{a+b+c}.$$