# Prove an inequality with square roots

Tags: inequality

Prove that
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{b+c}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{c+a}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{a+b}} > \sqrt{a+b+c}$$
if a, b, c are positive.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+a}} &gt; \sqrt{a+b+c}$ is true for positive a,b,c](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/fraca-sqrtab-fracb-sqrtbc-fracc-sqrtca-sqrtab)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{b+c}} > \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b+c}} $$

since $a+b+c > b+c$. Similarly

$$\frac{b}{\sqrt{c+a}} > \frac{b}{\sqrt{a+b+c}} $$
$$\frac{c}{\sqrt{a+b}} > \frac{c}{\sqrt{a+b+c}} $$

Combine these to get:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{b+c}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{c+a}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a+b}} > \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a+b+c}} = \sqrt{a+b+c}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as in the proof of the similar inequality

- [$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+a}} > \sqrt{a+b+c}$ is true for positive a,b,c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/fraca-sqrtab-fracb-sqrtbc-fracc-sqrtca-sqrtab)

$$
\frac{a}{\sqrt{b+c}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{c+a}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{a+b}} \\>
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b+c}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+c+a}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+a+b}}  \\= \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}
= \sqrt{a+b+c}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Set $a+b+c=3$, then RHS $=\sqrt3$. Then use the convex function $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3-x}}$ with Jensen to prove a tighter inequality, $LHS\geqslant \sqrt{\frac32}RHS$.